# How do I export fields of a content type in one website and import it into another website?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to set up a data export through views that includes the title and a couple of fields of a content type and import it into another website. I'm using Feeds and Views Data Export and also tried Views XML but is doesn't seem to work.

How do I export fields and import them by creating nodes in another website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a rss feed of your view or using [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) create a csv of your data.
2. Create the Content Type that will be the container for your new content. Or alternatively export the content type using the "Content Copy" module shipped with cck and then import it on the new site.
3. Using [Feeds](http://vimeo.com/8180911) Create a node importer to import your nodes. Details in the video linked.

Answer (score 0):

Remember see this: comparison of content import and export modules http://groups.drupal.org/node/21338 and his respective comments.

from all this options [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) (and also [Migrate extras](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras)) seems an interesting option to drupal 7 (is my opinion) because is flexible, and stable, altough maybe is best build a custom script to export and import your content.

Comment: You might also be able to use the features module: http://drupal.org/project/features to help out.

Comment: What I was hoping for was a feed that uses views and allows fields instead of the whole entity.

Answer (score 0):

Views lets you easily create any kind of RSS feeds of your content, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Bundle Copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) if it's structure you're trying to move. This is similar to CCK's Content Copy in Drupal 6.